# How to do a display list buffer in emacslisp

Tags: listview, emacs, elisp, emacs24

As shown in magit, dired, elget and of course Emacs Customize buffers, and many other modes,  there is the ability to create navigable lists in Emacs.

I will do some additional research myself, and will post updates.

But I wanted to reach out the the EmacsLisp community here to see if there was a standard way to do these sort of ncurses style interfaces, specifically a navigable list, I'll use El-Get as the model I'm trying to duplicate.

Assume Emacs24 if features are version specific.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll expand on Stefan's answer a little. tabulated-list-mode is indeed what you are looking for. Basically you define a derived mode with it's own mode-map. You then simply need to create a buffer, switch to your mode and then populate tabulated-list-entries and then call tabulated-list-init-header and tabulated-list-print.

You can see a simple example of usage with my [mark-list](https://github.com/stsquad/emacs-mark-tools/blob/master/mark-tools.el) extension.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the details, maybe `tabulated-list-mode` is a good start.